# Table level triggers in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

Does SQL Server support table-level triggers ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Table level triggers" - as opposed to row level?

Yes all triggers on tables in SQL Server are table level. It does not support row level triggers.

Comment: What other kind of triggers could you have besides table level? I don't even know what "row level triggers" means. LOL

Comment: @Richard - In a statement that affects multiple rows row level triggers fire once per changed row.

Comment: @Martin, doesn't that happen with a "table-level" trigger too?

Comment: @Richard - In SQL Server the triggers fire once per statement not per row. The row(s) affected (if any) are accessible through looking at the `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo tables in the trigger.

Comment: Ugh, I forgot about that. I rarely use triggers because I don't like them (its very easy to forget they are there) so its been a long time since I used them.

Comment: @Richard, maybe you used them recently but forgot that you used them?

Comment: whats the template for a table level trigger?